# Netsuite Date format leading zeros

Tags: netsuite

In many lists of netsuite the dates appear in the right format but the leading zeros are gone. Like
1/1/2018
1/12/2018
12/1/2018

We want it more consistent with the leading zeros like
01/01/2018
01/12/2018
12/01/2018

I don't see the setup. Is there's a way to do that without extensive scripting ?

Answer (score 0):

**Date Formats**

TRY

> DD/MM/YYYY

You can choose from U.S. or international formats for dates. Choose a format for dates in your account at Setup > Company > Preferences > General Preferences.

After you have chosen the format for dates, that format appears on reports, forms and data-entry pages.

You can get more help from 
 [NetSuite Help Center - Date Formats](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_n249143.html)

Comment: @markwagner If the above method doesn't work,you can achieve the goal only by scripting.

Comment: If you use scripting, use moment.js for any date/time related functionality.